# how to use variable in page attribute of jsp include tag?

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

how to use variable in page attribute of jsp include tag ?

```
<jsp:include page="/adminadvertisement?type=c80&action=showall" />
```

I want to insert a variable passed as parameter in page attribute .Something like

```
<jsp:include page="/adminadvertisement?type={$param.type}&action=showall" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`<jsp:param>`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/syntax/2.0/syntaxref2020.html#8828) (and fix your incorrect [EL expression](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info), it should follow `${}` syntax)

```html
<jsp:include page="/adminadvertisement">
    <jsp:param name="type" value="${param.type}" />
    <jsp:param name="action" value="showall" />
</jsp:include>
```

However, since it's to be derived from the request parameter, you should be able to use `${param.type}` inside the included JSP page page directly without passing it as `<jsp:param>`.

Answer (score 4):

Use `${param.type}` instead of `{$param.type}`, if this does not work use `param` tag:

```
<jsp:include page="/adminadvertisement"> 
    <jsp:param name="type" value="${param.type}"/>
</jsp:include>
```